# Why are Elastic Dynamic Templates not Working

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to create a dynamic mapping rule that indexes any fields starting or ending with "ip". The request below should do that, but it is not applying the right type. It should make the field types set to "ip". This is literally from the elastic docs. Any help appreciated.

```
PUT my-index
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "ip_fields": {
          "match_mapping_type": "*",
          "match":   ["ip*", "*ip"],
          "mapping": {
            "type": "ip"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

PUT my-index/_doc/1
{
  "three_ip": "12.12.12.12", 
  "ip_four":  "13.13.13.13" 
}
```

Here is the incorrect result. The type should be "ip", but it is not.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "ip_fields": {
          "match": "[ip*, *ip]",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "ip"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "properties": {
      "ip_four": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "three_ip": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are using **elasticsearch 7+**, if im not mistaken match lists released at **elasticsearch 8+**.

But you can use regexp expression to make work)

```
{
"mappings": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
        {
            "ip_fields": {
                "match_pattern": "regex",
                "match": "^ip_\\w+|\\w+_ip$",
                "mapping": {
                    "type": "ip"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
}
```

This is basically (starts with **ip_** or ends with **_ip**)

Comment: I'm using 8.7.1, but your answer worked.